# Dynamic table component that displays selected sObject's fields with specified header values

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, map, repeat

I have a problem with making a dynamic table component that displays selected `sObject` fields with specified header values.
The very first idea was to supply the component with an `apex:attrubite` of type `Map`,  containing a key-value pairs for column `headerValue` and `sObject` field name correspondingly. Then use `apex:repeat` to iterate through the collection and add appropriate headers and `apex:outputField` just like that:

#### Component

```
<apex:attribute name="collection" description="..." type="sObject[]" assignTo="{!sObjectCollection}"/>
<apex:attribute name="fields" description="..." type="Map<String,String>" assignTo="{!fieldsMap}"/>

<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!sObjectsCollection}" var="collectionItem">
    <apex:repeat value="{!fieldsMap.keySet()}" var="key">
        <apex:column headerValue="{!key}">
            <apex:outputField value="{!collectionItem.get(fieldsMap.get(key)}"/>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

#### Controller

```
public List<sObject> sObjectsCollection{ get; set; }
public Map<String, String> fieldsMap { get; set; }
```

But I get the error: `Unsupported type Map<String,String> encountered`.
I'm sure there is some better approach to get desired result.

---

I have also tried to get the `headerValues` from one `String` and the field names from another but then I don't know how to assign a proper `headerValue` to specific field name.  Any ideas?

Comment: I believe that it is a bug in salesforce and you cannot pass Map as attribute to custom component. Try create your own class that will wrap Map. Example for that, you can find  in this topic: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32554/passing-a-map-to-a-custom-component

Answer (score 0):

from the [Visualforce Developer’s Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_attribute.htm)

> Maps, specified using type="map". You don't need to specify the map's specific data type.

Have you tried this ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this as well. I have found a better approach to make this dynamic table and I will update my post as soon as I finish implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

Accepting maps in Components is unfortunately unsupported. Setting the type to simply `Map` will not cause the Component to actually accept `Map`s so we can just as well consider that option to be non-existent.

You'll have to create a wrapper class around your `Map`, then use that wrapper class as the `Type` in your `apex:attribute` and pass your map around like that.